# project angular : command npm start error

Tags: angular

When I try to start my angular 2 project in `cmd.exe` with the command: `npm start` I have this error message:

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
>
> npm ERR! argv "D:\NodeJs\node.exe"
>   "D:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.11.2
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script 'npm
>   run build'.
>
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
>   installed.
>
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the
>   angular-quickstart package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     npm run build
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
>   project with:
>
> npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
>
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     D:\Angular 2\bon\npm-debug.log"

And my package.json : "
"

```
name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.4",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
"
```

I don't know what is the problem...

Comment: What happens if you run "npm run build"?

Comment: Your script ended up in an unexpected way, most probably because of the `start` script. Try changing it until it works correctly.

Since your Node and NPM versions are up to date, this is the only possible issue

Comment: Alex Beugnet what can I put for the start script?

Answer (score -1):

Check your start script in package.json

```
"scripts": { "start": "ng serve" }
```

Or run directly using 
    ng serve --o

Comment: You realize that the question is related to a non cli project, right?